# AlertDialog doesn't close by itself when launching another activity by intent and then returning

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an alertDialog which allows user to go to settings to turn on location. Then, when I come back from settings app, alertDialog is still showing and I have to close it manually. Any ideas how to solve this ? This is my code:

```
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Location settings");
    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Location service is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            dialog.dismiss();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: where you are invoking showSettingsAlert(); ?

Comment: set cancable true to `alertDialog`

Comment: and may use `alertDialog.cancel();`

Comment: is Your AlertDialog global? if yes, follow snachmsm answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
            alertDialog.cancel();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);                
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, this is interesting approach. And it works, but meanwhile i found some different way by directly going to settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cancel()`method instead of `dismiss()` :

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);

        startActivity(intent);
        dialog.cancel();

    }
});
```